# How to add CSS background image for IE 8?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have wrote CSS for div add background image that image visible on FF, CH, ... but, it doesn't show on IE 8

**css file**

```
#headerrotetor{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1600px;
    max-height: 660px;
    background-image: url(images/hm_bg.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-size:contain;
}
```

**And I have maintain CSS for IE that file has**

```
#headerrotetor{
    height: 660px;
    width: 1600px;
}
```

Background image size 340Kb, can someone help me, thank you

Answer (score 0):

did you use the correct path ?

try applying background to the body tag. below code supports IE 4.0 upwards.

```
body {
    background-image: url('paper.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right top;
}
```

Note: IE8 and earlier do not support multiple background images on one element.